# Can I make Python tell me on exactly which character causes an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling, runtime-error

Python's errors only show what line errors occur on.

Example of a runtime error where knowing where in the line caused the error would save time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/clickbait/Projects/Python Projects/detail-processing.py", line 34, in <module>
    samples = [oldMatrix[x + pixel[0], y + pixel[1]][2] for pixel in pixelsToSample]
IndexError: image index out of range
```

It would be useful if errors also showed what column or character causes the error. Like in the example, I wouldn't need to check all 3 list indexes if the error pointed to where the problem was on the line.

Another of a runtime error where knowing where in the line caused the error would save time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/clickbait/Projects/stackpromo/main.py", line 482, in get
    postSlogan=tagLines[int(randomAd.tagLine)][JSON['post_type']].format(site=adSiteNames[randomAd.site]),
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not unicode
```

This line has a lot of indecies (`[xxx]`). I'd like to know which index causes the problem!

**Is there a setting (maybe a command-line flag) to make Python errors display the column/character as well as the line number that raises an exception?**

---

Syntax errors point do to the invalid syntax with a `^` symbol, but runtime errors don't point to which variable(s) cause(s) the errors.

Comment: The compiler does not retain column information, only row information.

Comment: Your code is tokenized, then turned into an *abstract syntax tree*, and that tree is then compiled to bytecode. By the time a runtime error is raised, only the line number is retained, not the exact character positions of the sub-expressions.

Comment: You can split out your list comprehension into a `for` loop with `append()` if you find debugging a list comprehension on one line too cumbersome.

Comment: These comments should be answers as they completely answer the question.

Comment: This also isn't a big deal. Under most circumstances, including in this situation, there's only so many places where something could've gone wrong. If you

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no such option. The Python compiler doesn't retain column positions as it tokenizes and parses source code. Only line numbers are retained in the resulting bytecode.

You can trivially split out your expression into a `for` loop with list appending if this bug is hard to debug otherwise:

```
samples = []
for pixel in pixelsToSample:
    a = x + pixel[0]
    b = y + pixel[1]
    m = oldMatrix[a, b]
    samples.append(m[2])
```

I find it easy enough to just use the Python debugger to step through the code however.

Answer (score 1):

Many run-time systems will return both the error and the offending value, but Python is not among them.  There are many layers to the implementation code; returning the object and index, as well as converting the object back into the string of your run-time expression, is more work.  It broadens the error-handling interface somewhat and consumes more time in execution.

There's also the trade-off that tracing the problem is rather easy in most cases.  Split this line out to individual steps and run the program again, to see where the error lies:

```
# samples = [oldMatrix[x + pixel[0], y + pixel[1]][2] for pixel in pixelsToSample]
dummy = []
for pixel in pixelsToSample:
    print pixel
    newx = x + pixel[0]
    newy = y + pixel[1]
    print oldMatrix[newx, newy]
    dummy.append(oldMatrix[newx, newy][2])
print dummy
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in a number of cases it is possible to get better resolution of where the error is by using a decompiler which maps bytecode offsets to parse fragments.

See my talk [Where am I now really?](https://rocky.github.io/pycon2018.co/#/) or the video for that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRQr1OroXUM).